# Powershell: Screenscraping http and returning specific lines as variables

Tags: powershell, web-scraping

I'm relatively new to PowerShell and have got to the limit of my knowledge. I'm writing a script to scrape the backup data from an internal webpage and then extract information from the scrape to manipulate and later display in excel.

```
$Yesterday = [DateTime]::Now.AddDays(-1)
$datestr = $Yesterday.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")
$WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$Results = $WebClient.DownloadString("http://fakeurl")
```

This results in a large amount of output containing http code as well as the data I'm interested in but all bunched up together. I then do this:

```
[StringSplitOptions]$option = "None"
[string[]]$separator = "</td>"
$SPL = $Results.Split($separator, $option)
```

This splits the data up into a more readable format. Here's a snippet of the section I'm 
interested in from $SPL.

```
<tr><td headers="HOST_NAME" class="t13dataalt">server01
<td headers="AUTOSYS_JOB" class="t13dataalt">nbu.os.wn.135b.server01
<td headers="START_TIME" class="t13dataalt">01-Aug-2011 21:23
<td headers="END_TIME" class="t13dataalt">01-Aug-2011 21:51
<td headers="BACKUP_TYPE" class="t13dataalt">differential
<td headers="SCHEDULE" class="t13dataalt">daily
<td align="right"  headers="SIZE_MB" class="t13dataalt">       2,091.18
<td headers="IMAGES" class="t13dataalt">1
<td headers="EXIT_STATUS" class="t13dataalt">0
</tr><tr><td headers="HOST_NAME" class="t13data">server02
<td headers="AUTOSYS_JOB" class="t13data">nbu.os.wn.135b.server02
<td headers="START_TIME" class="t13data">31-Jul-2011 21:22
<td headers="END_TIME" class="t13data">31-Jul-2011 21:41
<td headers="BACKUP_TYPE" class="t13data">differential
<td headers="SCHEDULE" class="t13data">daily
<td align="right"  headers="SIZE_MB" class="t13data">       2,496.31
<td headers="IMAGES" class="t13data">1
<td headers="EXIT_STATUS" class="t13data">0
```

From this I need to extract the Start and End time, to work out the elapsed time, and also return the EXIT_STATUS of the most recent backup. I've tried the following but I feel I may be barking up the wrong tree:

```
$Position = select-string -inputobject $SPL -pattern $datestr
```

$Position.matches results in:

```
PS C:\Scripts> $Position.matches

Groups   : {03-Aug-2011}
Success  : True
Captures : {03-Aug-2011}
Index    : 12056
Length   : 11
Value    : 03-Aug-2011
```

My theory was to do a substring using the Index added to the Length to extract the time value after date but I have no idea how to do that. I also think it's a bit primative. There must be an easier way of returning the line of information I need from that variable without counting to the spot and then ripping out the rest of the line?

---

OK, as I'm not sure how to add a section like this at the bottom of the page, I'm going to add it here.

This is my script at the moment and it runs through without any errors but doesn't return any results.

```
# Get yesterdays date and convert it to the required search format
    $Yesterday = [DateTime]::Now.AddDays(-1)
    $datestr = $Yesterday.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")

# Scrape the webpage
    $url = "http://fake-url"
    $WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
    $Results = $WebClient.DownloadString($url)

# Determine if the previous day is listed in the backups
    $IsDateThere = $Results.Contains($datestr)
        If ($IsDateThere){
            # split the data into rows
            [StringSplitOptions]$option = "None"
            [string[]]$separator = "</td>"
            $SPL = $Results.Split($separator, $option)

            #strip the data into a hash table
            $SPL | 
                Foreach-Object {
                    where {$_ -match 'headers="(.*)" class.*>(.*)'} |
                        ForEach-Object { 
                        @{
                                $matches[1] = ($matches[2]).trim() 
                            }
                        }
                }           
        }
        Else{
            Write-Host "Yesterday's date not found"
        }
```

Any ideas? I'm not sure what to do next to get the start time and end time of the most recent backup and the exit code as variables.

Answer (score 3):

I would approach it something like this

```
$html = @"
<tr><td headers="HOST_NAME" class="t13dataalt">server01
<td headers="AUTOSYS_JOB" class="t13dataalt">nbu.os.wn.135b.server01
<td headers="START_TIME" class="t13dataalt">01-Aug-2011 21:23
<td headers="END_TIME" class="t13dataalt">01-Aug-2011 21:51
<td headers="BACKUP_TYPE" class="t13dataalt">differential
<td headers="SCHEDULE" class="t13dataalt">daily
<td align="right"  headers="SIZE_MB" class="t13dataalt">       2,091.18
<td headers="IMAGES" class="t13dataalt">1
<td headers="EXIT_STATUS" class="t13dataalt">0
</tr><tr><td headers="HOST_NAME" class="t13data">server02
<td headers="AUTOSYS_JOB" class="t13data">nbu.os.wn.135b.server02
<td headers="START_TIME" class="t13data">31-Jul-2011 21:22
<td headers="END_TIME" class="t13data">31-Jul-2011 21:41
<td headers="BACKUP_TYPE" class="t13data">differential
<td headers="SCHEDULE" class="t13data">daily
<td align="right"  headers="SIZE_MB" class="t13data">       2,496.31
<td headers="IMAGES" class="t13data">1
<td headers="EXIT_STATUS" class="t13data">0
"@

$html -split "`r`n" | where {$_ -match 'start_time|end_time'} |
    ForEach {
        $pos = $_.IndexOf("headers")
        $begin = $pos+9
        $end = $_.IndexOf('"', $begin)

        new-object PSObject -Property @{
            Key   = $_.SubString($begin, $end-$begin)
            Value = Get-Date( $_.SubString( $_.IndexOf(">")+1 ) )
        }
    }
```

## Results

```
Key        Value               
---        -----               
START_TIME 8/1/2011 9:23:00 PM 
END_TIME   8/1/2011 9:51:00 PM 
START_TIME 7/31/2011 9:22:00 PM
END_TIME   7/31/2011 9:41:00 PM
```

Answer (score 1):

this isn't an orginal answer - just an alternate version of Doug's using reg ex to capture all the data:

```
$html -split "`n" | where {$_ -match 'headers="(.*)" class.*>(.*)'} |
    % { 
        @{
                $matches[1] = ($matches[2]).trim() 
            }
    }
```

**EDIT:** using the code in the question:

```
$Yesterday = [DateTime]::Now.AddDays(-1)
$datestr = $Yesterday.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")
$WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$Results = $WebClient.DownloadString("http://fakeurl")

[StringSplitOptions]$option = "None"
[string[]]$separator = "</td>"
$SPL = $Results.Split($separator, $option)

$SPL | 
    Foreach-Object {
        where {$_ -match 'headers="(.*)" class.*>(.*)'} |
            % { 
            @{
                    $matches[1] = ($matches[2]).trim() 
                }
            }
    }
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
    $SPL | 
        Foreach-Object {
            where {$_ -match 'headers="(.*)" class.*>(.*)'} |
                % { 
if (($matches[2]).trim() -eq $datestr ) { "$($matches[1]) is yesterday's back up" }
                }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I'll test this today and let you know how I get on. Can I pass the $SPL variable into the hash table instead of the string as above? @Doug Finke

Comment: yes, that should work as well (I'll change above to show how I believe it would work)

Comment: how do I expand on my original question below your answer?

Comment: Not sure if i get what you're asking there @jok5r. To make it clearer I've added your code in case that was it...?

Comment: thanks for that - I've edited my original question with the entire script I currently have and the question below. Hope that's ok? This will eventually be part of a function that returns 2 results to the main script. Duration and Exit Code status (failed or success). I'm trying to understand the Regex in your example but I'm not entirely sure what it does.

Comment: If I want to post at the bottom of this page, do I use the "Answer your question" button? I was worried that this would close my question as "Answered" and not allow me to post anymore. Is this incorrect?

Comment: I think I see what you need now - at the mo the regex is returning everything. The quick way (as I see it is to have an if (($matches[2]).trim() -eq $datestr ) { "$($matches[1]) is yesterday's back up" }.